# Cannot activate correct Python in remote computer

Tags: python, python-venv

I have moved a virtual environment onto a remote computer.  I am trying to activate python 3.8 but not having much luck.

The virtual environment I'm using was created using venv.  But I created it on my Mac and then moved it onto the target Linux computer.   The following demonstrates that the Linux computer has python 3.8

```
kylefoley@kfoley76:~/byu_corpus_small/venv_byu/bin$ ls
activate       activate_this.py  pip     pip3.8     python3
activate.csh   easy_install      pip2    python     python-config
activate.fish  easy_install-2.7  pip2.7  python2    wheel
Activate.ps1   easy_install-3.8  pip3    python2.7
```

I activated the virtual environment with the following commands:

```
kylefoley@kfoley76:~/byu_corpus_small$ source venv_byu/bin/activate
```

However, the following command shows that python 2.7 was activated

```
(venv_byu) kylefoley@kfoley76:~/byu_corpus_small/code$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

Further, when I ran one of my programs I got a syntax error that only python 2.7 would throw:

```
(venv_byu) kylefoley@kfoley76:~/byu_corpus_small/code$ python3 fix_mistakes.py
  File "fix_mistakes.py", line 113
    p = print
    p (f"{round(c - b,0)} seconds")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even when I run the command python3, it activated python 3.5 as demonstrated by the following:

```
(venv_byu) kylefoley@kfoley76:~/byu_corpus_small/code$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)
```

I even think that the computer is not even using my working environment but the default python interpreter due to the following:

```
(venv_byu) kylefoley@kfoley76:~/byu_corpus_small/code$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I would think that the intepreter would be in my virtual environment which would be:

```
/venv_byu/bin/python3
```

#####UPDATE

I was able to install venv on the linux but I'm still activating python 3.5.3

```
kylefoley@kfoley76:~/byu_corpus_small$ source venv_byu/bin/activate
(venv_byu) kylefoley@kfoley76:~/byu_corpus_small$ which python
/home/kylefoley/byu_corpus_small/venv_byu/bin/python
(venv_byu) kylefoley@kfoley76:~/byu_corpus_small$ python --version
Python 3.5.3
```

Apparently the environment I downloaded did not have 3.8

```
(venv_byu) kylefoley@kfoley76:~/byu_corpus_small/venv_byu/bin$ ls
activate      activate.fish  easy_install-3.5  pip3    python
activate.csh  easy_install   pip               pip3.5  python3
```

Now, I just need to figure out how to get 3.8

Comment: You probably got an error message when you tried to `activate`, can you confirm?

Comment: No, I did not get an error message when I tried to activate, but in any case let me try to create a virtual environment on the linux

Comment: As you can see from the terminal commands, the virtual environment is enclosed in parentheses as it should be

Comment: see update .....

Comment: How did you create the `venv`? Did you create it for `python3.8` or just for default `python3` version? Try to create new `venv` using `virtualenv -p python3.8 .env`, activate it and check python inside. It should work if you have `python3.8` installed of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual environments are not portable. You should create a new virtual environment on the destination computer and populate it with the packages you need. Listing them with `pip freeze` on your local computer or manually enumerating them in `requirements.txt` are two common approaches.

The standard virtual environment shipped with Python actually hard-codes the path of the virtual environment, so you can't even rename the directory locally, much less copy it to a different directory structure on a different computer.

The `activate` command needs to be run with `source` for various reasons, but that also means that it is not very robust against failures. For example, it can throw an error or fail silently, but still update your prompt so that it appears as if the virtual environment was successfully activated.

To create a new virtual environment on a computer where you have Python 3.8 installed as `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`, you can run

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 -m venv venv_byu
```

You then need to `activate` this environment, and `pip install` or otherwise populate it with the libraries you need.

`pip freeze` will list the exact versions of all installed packages, so it is more precise in getting exactly the same version of everything. If you manually list packages in `requirements.txt`, you don't *have* to specify a precise version of anything, and you can leave out packages which are pulled in as dependencies of the packages you actually specifically depend on.

Comment: I solved the problem.  I actually don't need `venv` now, but I might in the future.  And your advice helped.  I'm not using any special packages so I decided to just run the problem with `python3.8 my_program.py` and that did it. But thanks for the tip on installing venv3.8 in the future.  I really appreciate that.